# Is deploying/debugging to real phone is faster than emulator on Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We're starting exploring Xamarin.Form as a mobile development using Visual Studio 2015 on Surface Pro 2 machine with 8 GB RAM. We found that when we debugged/deployed into Visual Studio Emulator for Android. It takes a bit time to deploy.

I'm just wondering if we have a proper phone ie. Android device or iPhone will this make faster in term of deploying/debugging speed?

I'm appreciated your feedback.

Thanks
Isadewa

Comment: Usually it won't. When you deploy to a device (iPhone, Android etc) you are copying the entire app over a USB connection onto the device. When you deploy to an emulator, you a copying onto a local machine which will be limited by the drives speed.

Comment: I can't answer your question because I develop on Mac. But it would depend on your computer's configuration too. On Mac, deploying and running on the iPhone simulator is by orders of magnitude the fastest solution in most cases. Plus the advantage of being able to access the file system of your app directly, while you can't on Android (you have to use adb shell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure when you use  real device you are using the phones's cpu , Gpu , ram to run your app but when you try to use your pc every time you are starting a vm that takes resources from your computer and slows it down so you are probably using and ide and you may have some chrome tabs open so if you are that guy who open alot of chrome tabs , launch alot of apps at once defintly debug on your phone.

Comment: OK it's much faster to deploy/debug directly on the phone itself rather than emulator. That makes sense. How about if the development machine with higher RAM and new CPU, does it much help to run faster emulator?

Comment: There are some things that can not be tested without a device , for example push notifications in ios apps , sim functions , also i have a very capable machine but i find it much faster to use my phone to test apps , also it enables me to show people , friends what i am working on directly from my personal phone , so if you can afford to get a real device it will definitely be helpful.

Comment: With the real device ie tablet/phone for transferring app from development machine, do I need a USB 3 connection on tablet? Or USB 2 is enough?

Comment: USB 2.0 is okay you are using it to just move the installer file to your phone then the compiler automatically installs the app on  the phone , even while live debuging , i have tried it and it works absolutely okay

Answer (score 2):

for sure testing and debuging your application on mobile device is much better for the reasons below:

1. Emulators are virtual machine that consumes memory and processing power from you computer which makes you computer much slower, which doesn't hapen when you debug on Mobile.
2. Mobile devices are better when your app is developed to consume and access mobile resources like camera , contact, push notification  ... etc.

The only reason that you can make benefit of emulator , if you want to test your application on a specific mobile device and you don't have it for the moment , then I would prefer to configure an emulator with the specific mobile aspects and test my app on it .

Comment: With the real device ie tablet/phone for transferring app from development machine, do I need a USB 3 connection on tablet? Or USB 2 is enough?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely real device debugging fast as compare to emulatore because emulator taking lot of time to launch even though you configure different cpu, and more ram but real device will be feasible for debugging.

Prefer always real devices because its properly give response while debugging.

Comment: With the real device ie tablet/phone for transferring app from development machine, do I need a USB 3 connection on tablet? Or USB 2 is enough?